# Daemon will not start in Windows GUI

Tags: daemon

Here is a snippet of my log where the error begins:

> 2023-12-19 11:59:58.130   [P2P7]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1697    Synced 2916476/3042877 (95%, 126401 left)
> 2023-12-19 12:00:47.547 [P2P7]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1697    Synced 2916496/3042877 (95%, 126381 left)
> 2023-12-19 12:01:06.012 [P2P7]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1697    Synced 2916516/3042877 (95%, 126361 left)
> 2023-12-19 12:01:46.032 [P2P7]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1697    Synced 2916536/3042877 (95%, 126341 left, 15% of total synced, estimated 1.3 days left)
> 2023-12-19 15:20:39.122 540 INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
> 2023-12-19 15:20:39.124 540 INFO    global  src/daemon/main.cpp:309 Monero 'Fluorine Fermi' (v0.18.3.1-release)
> 2023-12-19 15:20:43.031 540 ERROR   msgwriter   src/common/scoped_message_writer.h:102  Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081
> 2023-12-19 15:21:00.152 5756    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
> 2023-12-19 15:21:00.152 5756    INFO    global  src/daemon/main.cpp:309 Monero 'Fluorine Fermi' (v0.18.3.1-release)
> 2023-12-19 15:21:00.152 5756    INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:53    Initializing cryptonote protocol...
> 2023-12-19 15:21:00.152 5756    INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:58    Cryptonote protocol initialized OK
> 2023-12-19 15:21:00.152 5756    INFO    global  src/daemon/core.h:64    Initializing core...
> 2023-12-19 15:21:00.152 5756    INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:523 Loading blockchain from folder C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\lmdb ...
> 2023-12-19 15:21:02.163 9704    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
> 2023-12-19 15:21:02.163 9704    INFO    global  src/daemon/main.cpp:309 Monero 'Fluorine Fermi' (v0.18.3.1-release)
> 2023-12-19 15:21:06.505 9704    ERROR   msgwriter   src/common/scoped_message_writer.h:102  Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081
> 2023-12-19 15:21:06.615 5756    INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:698 Loading checkpoints
> 2023-12-19 15:21:06.615 5756    INFO    global  src/daemon/core.h:81    Core initialized OK
> 2023-12-19 15:21:06.615 5756    INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:64 Initializing p2p server...
> 2023-12-19 15:21:06.657 5756    INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:69 p2p server initialized OK
> 2023-12-19 15:21:06.657 5756    INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:63 Initializing core RPC server...
> 2023-12-19 15:21:06.657 5756    INFO    global  contrib/epee/include/net/http_server_impl_base.h:79 Binding on 127.0.0.1 (IPv4):18081
> 2023-12-19 15:21:06.699 5756    INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:69 core RPC server initialized OK on port: 18081
> 2023-12-19 15:21:06.741 5756    INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:74 Starting core RPC server...
> 2023-12-19 15:21:06.741 [SRV_MAIN]  INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:79 core RPC server started ok
> 2023-12-19 15:21:06.741 [SRV_MAIN]  INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:79 Starting p2p net loop...
> 2023-12-19 15:21:07.743 [P2P7]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:1826
> 2023-12-19 15:21:07.744 [P2P7]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:1826    **********************************************************************
> 2023-12-19 15:21:07.744 [P2P7]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:1826    The daemon will start synchronizing with the network. This may take a long time to complete.
> 2023-12-19 15:21:07.745 [P2P7]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:1826
> 2023-12-19 15:21:07.745 [P2P7]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:1826    You can set the level of process detailization through "set_log <level|categories>" command,
> 2023-12-19 15:21:07.746 [P2P7]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:1826    where  is between 0 (no details) and 4 (very verbose), or custom category based levels (eg, *:WARNING).
> 2023-12-19 15:21:07.746 [P2P7]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:1826
> 2023-12-19 15:21:07.747 [P2P7]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:1826    Use the "help" command to see the list of available commands.
> 2023-12-19 15:21:07.747 [P2P7]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:1826    Use "help " to see a command's documentation.
> 2023-12-19 15:21:07.748 [P2P7]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:1826    **********************************************************************
> 2023-12-19 15:21:08.715 4612    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
> 2023-12-19 15:21:08.715 4612    INFO    global  src/daemon/main.cpp:309 Monero 'Fluorine Fermi' (v0.18.3.1-release)
> 2023-12-19 15:21:09.657 4612    INFO    msgwriter   src/common/scoped_message_writer.h:102  Height: 2916536, target: 2916536 (100%)
> 2023-12-19 15:21:09.657 4612    INFO    msgwriter   src/common/scoped_message_writer.h:102  Downloading at 0 kB/s
> 2023-12-19 15:21:09.657 4612    INFO    msgwriter   src/common/scoped_message_writer.h:102  Next needed pruning seed: 1
> 2023-12-19 15:21:09.657 4612    INFO    msgwriter   src/common/scoped_message_writer.h:102  0 peers
> 2023-12-19 15:21:09.657 4612    INFO    msgwriter   src/common/scoped_message_writer.h:102  Remote Host                        Peer_ID   State   Prune_Seed          Height  DL kB/s, Queued Blocks / MB
> 2023-12-19 15:21:09.657 4612    INFO    msgwriter   src/common/scoped_message_writer.h:102  0 spans, 0 MB
> 2023-12-19 15:21:09.657 4612    INFO    msgwriter   src/common/scoped_message_writer.h:102  []
> 2023-12-19 15:21:15.761 [P2P9]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:409 [167.172.82.200:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 2916536 -> 3043157 [Your node is 126621 blocks (5.8 months) behind]
> 2023-12-19 15:21:15.761 [P2P9]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:409 SYNCHRONIZATION started
> 2023-12-19 15:21:43.407 [P2P5]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1697    Synced 2916556/3043157 (95%, 126601 left)
> 2023-12-19 15:21:53.209 [P2P5]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1697    Synced 2916576/3043157 (95%, 126581 left)
> 2023-12-19 15:22:26.649 [P2P5]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1697    Synced 2916596/3043157 (95%, 126561 left)
> 2023-12-19 15:22:58.898 [P2P5]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1697    Synced 2916616/3043157 (95%, 126541 left)
> 2023-12-19 15:23:05.275 [P2P5]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1697    Synced 2916636/3043157 (95%, 126521 left)
> 2023-12-19 15:23:16.610 [P2P5]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1697    Synced 2916656/3043157 (95%, 126501 left)
> 2023-12-19 15:31:35.629 7628    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
> 2023-12-19 15:31:35.630 7628    INFO    global  src/daemon/main.cpp:309 Monero 'Fluorine Fermi' (v0.18.3.1-release)
> 2023-12-19 15:31:42.772 7628    ERROR   msgwriter   src/common/scoped_message_writer.h:102  Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081
> 2023-12-19 15:32:00.589 7156    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
> 2023-12-19 15:32:00.589 7156    INFO    global  src/daemon/main.cpp:309 Monero 'Fluorine Fermi' (v0.18.3.1-release)
> 2023-12-19 15:32:00.589 7156    INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:53    Initializing cryptonote protocol...
> 2023-12-19 15:32:00.589 7156    INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:58    Cryptonote protocol initialized OK
> 2023-12-19 15:32:00.589 7156    INFO    global  src/daemon/core.h:64    Initializing core...
> 2023-12-19 15:32:00.589 7156    INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:523 Loading blockchain from folder C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\lmdb ...
> 2023-12-19 15:32:01.571 7156    WARNING blockchain.db.lmdb  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:75   Failed to query m_blocks: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
> 2023-12-19 15:32:01.571 7156    ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:624 Error opening database: Failed to query m_blocks: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
> 2023-12-19 15:32:01.571 7156    INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:75    Stopping cryptonote protocol...
> 2023-12-19 15:32:01.571 7156    INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:79    Cryptonote protocol stopped successfully
> 2023-12-19 15:32:01.571 7156    ERROR   daemon  src/daemon/main.cpp:377 Exception in main! Failed to initialize core
> 2023-12-19 15:32:02.600 9524    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
> 2023-12-19 15:32:02.600 9524    INFO    global  src/daemon/main.cpp:309 Monero 'Fluorine Fermi' (v0.18.3.1-release)
> 2023-12-19 15:32:07.347 9524    ERROR   msgwriter   src/common/scoped_message_writer.h:102  Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081
> 2023-12-19 15:32:09.540 8984    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
> 2023-12-19 15:32:09.540 8984    INFO    global  src/daemon/main.cpp:309 Monero 'Fluorine Fermi' (v0.18.3.1-release)
> 2023-12-19 15:32:12.370 8984    ERROR   msgwriter   src/common/scoped_message_writer.h:102  Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081
> 2023-12-19 15:32:14.580 7492    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO

This may have occurred because I ran out of HD space. I cleared up about 23 GB but now the daemon won't start up again. Please advise! Thank you!